# React Native location permission doesn't work in Android 10 but does work in Android 9

Tags: android, react-native, permissions

Issue :
I'm using the react-native-permissions library in my react native app. The code was working perfectly fine in Android devices with OS 9 or below i.e, when prompted to access the device location and if the user grants it the location, the app has access to the device location.

But in Android 10, when the location prompt first appears, and I either select "Allow all the time" or "Allow only while the app is in use", the app is still not able to access the location even though when I check the App info of this app, location shows enabled in the Permissions section. 
Now when I turn on the system-wide GPS from the notifications manually, then the app is able to fetch the location.
I don't understand what I'm missing here.

I'm using a Oneplus 6t. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when working with the **location** in the Android.

I believe you are using [React Native Geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) which usually used `android.location` API on android.

This API is not recommended by Google because it is less accurate and slower than the recommended Google Location Services API.

In order to use it with React Native, use the [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service) module. This module has similar looking API and support the latest Android versions. I was able to fix the issue using this package.